# How to create another array set that guarantees prediction

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, validation

```
  Card#0           Card#1            Card#2         Card#3           Card#4
1, 3,  5,  7      2, 3, 6, 7     4, 5, 6, 7     8, 9, 10,11      16, 17, 18, 19
9, 11, 13, 15    10,11,14,15     12,13,14,15    12,13,14,15      20, 21, 22, 23
17, 19, 21, 23   18,19,22,23     20,21,22,23    24,25,26,27      24, 25, 26, 27
25, 27, 29, 31    26,27,30,31   28,29,30,31    28,29,30,31      28, 29, 30, 31
```

This can Predict any number between 1 and 31.  So it can predict the day of your birthday by telling the programmer, myself what cards does your number appear in.  You take the first number of a card that the number appeared and and add the first numbers that appear on the card.
For Example:

Number I selected is 27.  The #27 appears on cards #0,1,3,4.  The corresponding first numbers that appears on each of the cards it would be #1 + 2 + 8 + 16 = 27

By knowing doing this arithmetic i believe we see a log(n) alglorithm being used since it cut the code in halves and completed in about 2-3 functions.

My question is how can I expand this array set by increasing the parameter number to create more sets of arrays that can be perfectly sorted and will produce an extra card more than #4.  In other words how can I make this code prediction parameters wider and still execute O(log(n) linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this works is really just binary encoding. A number exists on card `n` if its `n`th bit (from the right) is turned on.

So, for example, 19 = 10011<sub>2</sub>, so it shows up on cards 0, 1, and 4.

Thus, if you want to make this system work for numbers `1..n`, you just need the number of cards to be equal to the number of bits in `n`. Then, on each card, just include all numbers with that bit flipped on.

Here's a demo, but please take the time to think about how you would implement this first and then seek to understand my code, not copy it:

```python
n = int(input())
digits = len(bin(n)) - 2

def get_card(place):
	card = []
	for x in range(1, n + 1):
		if x & (1 << place):
			card.append(x)
	return card

for x in range(digits):
	print(f"Card {x + 1}:", get_card(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIXXySmGLiSDVajdlbryGCISm6QGyjTEFCLi2WOioOBy3ryfz93DdaY2JYI9WArCkluCQOTKjjbcsjppEhdLghBhAzvOlTYw6nAepFfCTXLQ2HFWruw@njgzs4eY28BLGrVoaiBYQ1NczJr8WoFooO/hG2bv@FY6p0mJiJx5HRZPUGTO/wo/aCXnfGE21aGMP2JZeXZV/cOLiCm1zQs)

I notice you mention a time complexity restriction as well. I haven't checked if my code conforms to that - my goal here is purely to just give a demo of what this might look like - there is probably a more efficient way to get the list of all numbers with that bit flipped on (although, I think this is actually `O(n log n)`, but I'm not sure).

Comment: You did more than enough thank you for existing and sharing.